# NSLogging UILabel's text outputs null

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, nslog

I have a custom view controller called `TimerViewController` and subclasses of this called `FirstViewController` and `FourthViewController`.

I declared an instance of `FirstViewController` in `FirstViewController`'s `.`h named `controller`.

In the `viewDidLoad` method of `FourthViewController`'s `.m`, I have:

```objectivec
controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainController"];
```

In the storyboard, I've declared the view controller ID as `mainController` and declared a custom class of `FourthViewController`. Then, in `FourthViewController`'s `.m` I have:

```objectivec
controller.mainLab.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"This is a string"];
NSLog(@"%@", controller.mainLab.text);
```

This, however, outputs `(null)`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: What do you get if you log mainLab?

Comment: What is mainLab? Is it an IBOutlet? Is it in the same controller as where this code is?

Comment: It's an IBOutlet. I properly connected it to the XIB. It is in the same controller

Answer (score 2):

`mainLab` must be `nil`. So your outlet probably isn't connected to your XIB.

---

As an aside, using `stringWithFormat:` with a string that isn't a format is wasteful.

Comment: I did connect my outlet to my XIB. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your neglecting to tell us something about the rest of your project, im just not sure what it is.

I fired up Xcode just to run through this real quick and the process is simple.

Drag UI Label to your XIB

Control click from label to your .h

For testing I did

```
#import "SOViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mainLabel.text = @"This is my label";
    NSLog(@"%@", self.mainLabel.text);
}
```

My .h looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SOViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mainLabel;
@end
```

Is this part of a custom class? Is there something else going on? If its a vanilla label it should work without issue using the aforementioned code.

Comment: It's a subclass of a custom class. I declared the property and synthesized it in this custom class's .h and .m . I was trying to simplify the question, but I guess I need to give the full code. Return to post for complete code

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your `mainLab` has not yet been created. When you call methods on nil objects, the method automatically returns nil. Make sure you actually create the label before running this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the label (or any other UI element) of another controller right after you instantiate it, because its viewDidLoad method has not yet run. If you want to set the text of  a label in another controller, you have to pass the text to that controller, and have it set the text on the label in its viewDidLoad method. So instead of the this:

```
controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainController"];
controller.mainLab.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"This is a string"];
```

You need to do this:

```
controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainController"];
controller.mainLabText = @"This is a string";
```

where mainLabText is a string property you create in FourthViewController. Then populate the label in FourthViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
self.mainLab.text = self.mainLabText;
```